# How to make Custom color in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, please suggest how to make custom color for a control and add it to property-> backColor Section.?

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really belong here on SO but you can right click on one of the white color boxes in the two bottom-most rows and then select the color.

Comment: Thanks man, really Helpful. Also can u pls tell me how to set their alpha value?

Comment: I don't know if you can do that without using Color.FromArgb.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can type a comma separated RGB value into the BackColor value in the property grid, eg:

150, 250, 70

Comment: yes i have done this, u given so late reply but your answer is correct.

Comment: Actually it has to be semicolon-sparated: either : "150; 250; 70" or in hex: "0x12;0x34;0x56". (At least in VS2015)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method:

```
Color clr = Color.FromArgb(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue)
```

Comment: I know this, but i want to add this color in Property of the panel as shown in image http://i772.photobucket.com/albums/yy9/yogeshkmrsoni/color/clr_zps92a728b9.png (white blank color sections), I want to use this color in design time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this done using some User interface:

You could find out where the custom colors are stored for the current user, and then add one.

Or, create your own [`UITypeEditor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), that contains the colors you want. Probably you have to inherit from `Form`, and override the `BackColor` property to add the correct attributes.

---

Much easier is to just set it in code, using the Argb code from the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can not.

What you see is a default editor for `Color` type (create own control, add there public property of `Color` type and it will also uses it). *Web* and *System* tabs working fine. First tab is a sort of *custom* color pickup part from standard color pickup dialog.

I think MS fails to make popup editor to show modal dialog (because popup will get closed). =D

Perhaps colors there are taken from Windows color dialog, so you have to arrange it there (perhaps you can use winapi to do that). /shrug